# Xamarin Forms iOS Safe area resizes on load?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.shell

Slightly odd one. I have built an app in Xamarin Forms (Shell) and everything works fine on Android. When I navigate to a new page in ios (iphone 11 pysical device), the screen seems to pop down and resize. I think this is related to the safe area property used in the views that is happening a little bit too slow as it appears to be in the safe areas and then resizes to be in the safe zone.

No impact on Android.

I can't recreate in a new project but my current project has significant time investment and i don't want to start again... I can't retro fit into my existing project, the problem persists.

Some example code below, but the weird bit is that it seems to work in a new project so im looking for guidance on what else might be set somewhere to debug this issue. Any thoughts? Can provide additional code examples as needed, just let me know.

I've tried upgrading and downgrading packages etc no effect.

Packages

I navigate using

```
   private async Task ExecuteAddPageCommand()
        {
            await PushAsync(new AddPagePage());
        }
```

where PushAsync is in my baseviewmodel

```
    public async Task<bool> PushAsync(Page page)
    {
        try
        {
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(Utilities.Routes.ErrorModalPage);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the pages have the standard properties (example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             Visual="Material"
             x:Class="namespace:Thing.Views.AddPage"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Thing.Converters"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Thing.Controls"
             xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:Thing.Utilities"
             >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converter:IntToEnumConverter x:Key="IntToEnum"/>
      <converter:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBool"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>

           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <controls:PageHeader Grid.Row="0" ShowBackButton="true"
                           HeaderTitle="New Thing"
                HeaderImage="{x:Static utilities:Icons.AddMenuIcon}" 
                                 BackCommand="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}"/>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
          <Label Text="What do you want to call this?" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}"/>
          <Entry Text="{Binding Name.Value}" Placeholder="E.g. My shiny thing"/> 
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}"></Button>
          <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
      </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Invoke the line `On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);` .

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your message. I have set this in the xaml of each page required (which is in the example). Is this c# code different? Or just the same way of setting the property but in code behind?

Comment: They have the same effect .

Comment: Ok. As you can see in the code, the property is being set in the XAML but i experiencing this odd pop effect on loading the page. What else could be impacting this? Is there a version limit i.e. 4.5? etc

Comment: You could update the version of XF to the latest and check again .

Comment: I've both updated to latest as well as downgrading (as per other comment). Neither fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and updating to the latest (4.8.1269) did not help. It seems this problem was introduced in 4.7.1260. I downgraded to 4.7.1239 and all is well again.

Comment: I downgraded to 4.7.1239 but still happening. I'm wondering if it is a visual studio update and something to do with how it builds?

Comment: Looks like they just released an update to 4.7 (4.7.1351) that addresses this issue. This version does work on my project, I hope it will on yours. Here are the release notes. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases/tag/release-4.7.0-sr6

Comment: i am still not sure where this issue is as my local client produced the issue but I built it in Azure DevOps and it worked fine! So it's something additional to the xamarin package I think. That 4.7.0 sr6 does sound exactly like the problem though so hopefully will be resolved locally soon as well!